# Logical implication with 1 variable

Tags: variables, logic, implication

I have the following statements in my knowledge base, but there is a premise with only 1 variable (refer to 3rd line). I'm attempting to build a truth table for this, but the 3rd premise gets me confused as there is only 1 condition to decide the implied condition.

```
p ^ q ^ r => s;
q ^ r => t;
t => u;   <---- confused line.
p;
s;
```

For example, according to my knowledge:

```
p | q | p=>q    
--------------    
0 | 0 | 1    
0 | 1 | 1    
1 | 0 | 0    
1 | 1 | 1
```

But how do I go about constructing the truth table for 3rd statement here. There's only 1 variable to decide 'u'.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The truth table would involve `t` and `t=>u`; from there you would try to decide `u`:

```
t | t=>u | u    
--------------    
0 | 0    | not possible
0 | 1    | 0 or 1
1 | 0    | 0
1 | 1    | 1
```

If you want `t=>u` to be 1, then if `t` is 1, `u` has to be `1`; and if `t` is 0, then `u` can be either 0 or 1.